# Error Read Certificate (pkcs12) from Server (Java)

Tags: java, server, certificate, pkcs#12

i'm trying to read a pkcs12 certificate from the server, and after that, i have to use it for Get and Post...
So, i generated the PrivateKey.pem , signing_request.csr, and finally the pkcs12file.p12 (plus certificate.cer) using openssl and the copy and paste this certificate in a folder on my server.

Now when i try to read this Cert.p12 whit this **CODE**:

```java
w_NOMECER = CPLib.LRTrim(pFile)+"KEYS/"+CPLib.LRTrim(w_FOLDER)+"/"+CPLib.LRTrim(w_PIVA)+".p12";
...

clientCertPassword = CPLib.LRTrim(w_AEPWDP12);
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(w_NOMECER);
keyStore.load(fis, clientCertPassword.toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(keyStore, clientCertPassword.toCharArray());
KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagers, null,new SecureRandom());
```

I Get the **ERROR**:

```
[http-bio-9080-exec-2] : DEBUG  : wgae_bviewallcensR : ***** FIND certs in: /usr/tomcat7/webapps/App/KEYS/name_company/p12file.p12
[Timer-0] : WARN   : CPStdCounter : Generic error occurred at 10:09:55 041ms Friday 04 November originating thread http-bio-9080-exec-2 for user SPContext of user:13.0 guest:false company:005 username: admin                                    last accessed:Fri Nov 04 10:09:54 CET 2016 with stacktrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at wgae_bviewallcensR.Page_1(wgae_bviewallcensR.java:506)
at wgae_bviewallcensR.Run(wgae_bviewallcensR.java:602)
at wgae_bviewallcens.ExecuteRoutine(wgae_bviewallcens.java:150)
at wgae_bviewallcens.Begin(wgae_bviewallcens.java:300)
at wgae_bviewallcens.doProcess(wgae_bviewallcens.java:63)
at SPServlet.doAlways(spservlet.java:135)
at SPRoutineServlet.doAlways(sproutineservlet.java:111)
at SPServlet.doPost(spservlet.java:112)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at SPServlet.service(spservlet.java:2966)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at SPInvoker.service(spinvoker.java:171)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 46 more
Full stacktrace of cause:sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at wgae_bviewallcensR.Page_1(wgae_bviewallcensR.java:506)
    at wgae_bviewallcensR.Run(wgae_bviewallcensR.java:602)
    at wgae_bviewallcens.ExecuteRoutine(wgae_bviewallcens.java:150)
    at wgae_bviewallcens.Begin(wgae_bviewallcens.java:300)
    at wgae_bviewallcens.doProcess(wgae_bviewallcens.java:63)
    at SPServlet.doAlways(spservlet.java:135)
    at SPRoutineServlet.doAlways(sproutineservlet.java:111)
    at SPServlet.doPost(spservlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at SPServlet.service(spservlet.java:2966)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at SPInvoker.service(spinvoker.java:171)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 46 more
Full stacktrace of cause:sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at wgae_bviewallcensR.Page_1(wgae_bviewallcensR.java:506)
    at wgae_bviewallcensR.Run(wgae_bviewallcensR.java:602)
    at wgae_bviewallcens.ExecuteRoutine(wgae_bviewallcens.java:150)
    at wgae_bviewallcens.Begin(wgae_bviewallcens.java:300)
    at wgae_bviewallcens.doProcess(wgae_bviewallcens.java:63)
    at SPServlet.doAlways(spservlet.java:135)
    at SPRoutineServlet.doAlways(sproutineservlet.java:111)
    at SPServlet.doPost(spservlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at SPServlet.service(spservlet.java:2966)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at SPInvoker.service(spinvoker.java:171)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Do you want to configure a SSL channel for inbound connections to your server or you want to connect to a third party server that requires client certificate authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issues:
I have added this 2 lines of code in the control panel of Tomcat:

**-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\ZWeb\jdk7\jre\lib\security\namefile

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pwd**

But now i have another Error:

```
07 Nov 2016 15:45:03,605 [http-bio-9080-exec-7] : DEBUG  : wgae_bviewallcensR : ***** FIND certs in: /usr/tomcat7/webapps/App/KEYS/name_company/p12file.p12
07 Nov 2016 15:45:04,157 [Timer-1] : WARN   : CPStdCounter : 
    Generic error occurred at 15:45:04 056ms Monday 07 November originating thread http-bio-9080-exec-7 for user SPContext of 
    user:21.0 guest:false company:002 username: admin last accessed:Mon Nov 07 15:45:03 
    CET 2016 with stacktrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at wgae_bviewallcensR.Page_1(wgae_bviewallcensR.java:506)
    at wgae_bviewallcensR.Run(wgae_bviewallcensR.java:602)
    at wgae_bviewallcens.ExecuteRoutine(wgae_bviewallcens.java:150)
    at wgae_bviewallcens.Begin(wgae_bviewallcens.java:300)
    at wgae_bviewallcens.doProcess(wgae_bviewallcens.java:63)
    at SPServlet.doAlways(spservlet.java:135)
    at SPRoutineServlet.doAlways(sproutineservlet.java:111)
    at SPServlet.doPost(spservlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at SPServlet.service(spservlet.java:2966)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at SPInvoker$Initializer.service(spinvoker.java:408)
    at SPInvoker.service(spinvoker.java:171)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
    at sun.security.ssl.DummyX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1010)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 41 more
Full stacktrace of cause:java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
    at sun.security.ssl.DummyX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1010)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at wgae_bviewallcensR.Page_1(wgae_bviewallcensR.java:506)
    at wgae_bviewallcensR.Run(wgae_bviewallcensR.java:602)
    at wgae_bviewallcens.ExecuteRoutine(wgae_bviewallcens.java:150)
    at wgae_bviewallcens.Begin(wgae_bviewallcens.java:300)
    at wgae_bviewallcens.doProcess(wgae_bviewallcens.java:63)
    at SPServlet.doAlways(spservlet.java:135)
    at SPRoutineServlet.doAlways(sproutineservlet.java:111)
    at SPServlet.doPost(spservlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at SPServlet.service(spservlet.java:2966)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at SPInvoker$Initializer.service(spinvoker.java:408)
    at SPInvoker.service(spinvoker.java:171)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```